# Rasterio: Write Grid to TIFF

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I made a point density grid [using the steps here](https://pygis.io/docs/e_summarize_vector.html#count-points-in-rectangular-or-hexagonal-grid-or-by-polygon) and after reading the Rasterio documentation I am trying to write it out as TIFF using Rasterio with a resolution of 250. Here's my code:

```
area_grid [7866 rows x 3 columns] attribute table looks like this:

                                               geometry  Grid_ID  Count
0     POLYGON ((-2061272.927 869431.042, -2063772.92...        0      0
1     POLYGON ((-2061272.927 878091.296, -2063772.92...        1      0
2     POLYGON ((-2061272.927 886751.550, -2063772.92...        2      0
3     POLYGON ((-2061272.927 895411.804, -2063772.92...        3      0
4     POLYGON ((-2061272.927 904072.058, -2063772.92...        4      0
...                                                 ...      ...    ...
7861  POLYGON ((-1498772.927 1722466.064, -1501272.9...     7861      0
7862  POLYGON ((-1498772.927 1731126.318, -1501272.9...     7862      0
7863  POLYGON ((-1498772.927 1739786.572, -1501272.9...     7863      0
7864  POLYGON ((-1498772.927 1748446.826, -1501272.9...     7864      0
7865  POLYGON ((-1498772.927 1757107.081, -1501272.9...     7865      0
```

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import Affine

def export_grid(Z, filename):

    x, y = area_grid(x, y)
  
    Z1 = np.exp(-2 * np.log(2) * ((x - 0.5) ** 2 + (y - 0.5) ** 2) / 1 ** 2)
    Z2 = np.exp(-3 * np.log(2) * ((x + 0.5) ** 2 + (y + 0.5) ** 2) / 2.5 ** 2)
    Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

    # Get resolution
    xres = (x[-1] - x[0]) / 250.0
    yres = (y[-1] - y[0]) / 250.0

    # Set transform
    transform = Affine.translation(x[0] - xres / 2, y[0] - yres / 2) * Affine.scale(xres, yres)
    print(transform)

    # Export raster
    with rasterio.open(
            filename,
            mode = "w",
            driver = "GTiff",
            height = Z.shape[0],
            width = Z.shape[1],
            count = 1,
            dtype = Z.dtype,
            crs = proj,
            transform = transform,
    ) as new_dataset:
            new_dataset.write(Z, 1)

# Export raster
export_raster(Z = area_grid, filename = "newGrid.tif")
```

Error Message:

> UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'x' where it is not associated with a value

The goal is to write to TIFF using Rasterio. Any ideas?

Comment: should it be `area_grid[x, y]`?

Comment: 1. you define `export_grid` but try to call an undefined `export_raster`. 2. None of `area_grid`, `x` or `y` are defined in your `export_grid` function. You pass in `Z` but then don't use it and overwrite it.